# Working with array from string.split function

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have a blob of text like this, called `body`:

```
images: OK
default: OK
...
```

So I'm trying to work with it concisely, like so:

```
   for (str in body.split('\n')) {
       console.log(str);
   }
```

but I just get a list of numbers (the indices of each element). Why is this happening? Further more, I can't seem to do filter functions on this because of this behavior:

```
body.split('\n').filter(function(str){ return str && str.length > 0; });
```

just returns the whole array even if there are empty elements.

Comment: `for-in` loops through the *property names* of an object, not their values. The linked question goes into some detail about how to loop through arrays and array-like things.

Comment: Re the second part of your question: That code won't keep empty entries (https://jsfiddle.net/o6e2L1uu/), so apparently they aren't empty. (Also note that you don't need the `&& str.length > 0` part, `""` is falsy, and any other string is truthy.) You might throw a `trim` in (`return str.trim();`) in case they consist only of whitespace.

Comment: Learned something new, thanks!

Comment: Or more concisely, `body.split('\n').filter(Boolean)`.